# Is it possible to create global settings that are visible to all classes in the project? [Like modules in VB]

Tags: c#

I am creating a project with many classes. I need to have a kind of settings class AKA module in VB that is accessible from all other classes. I want to know a method to achieve that without creating a separate settings object and passing it to each other class constructor.

Thanks

Comment: Using a module to manage settings is not a particular good way, neither in C# nor in VB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a static class with static fields

```
public static class Settings
{
  public static string a = "a";
  public static string b = "b";
  public static bool c = true;
}
```

and in your other classes

```
if(Settings.c) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class. This has the bonus of working with the [standard .NET config files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx).

As far as I know, `My.Settings` is a wrapper around this class.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to use it?

Comment: @deadlock - there are examples in the linked article.

Comment: thanks. I will be using that in future project that needs settings to be saved and loaded each time the program fires. +1 for you Oded.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create a [public static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Under the covers, that's all VB does anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I just did.  This uses YAXLib (http://yaxlib.codeplex.com/) but you could use any serializer.  I don't know how good the example is though.

```
public class FrameworkSettings
{
    public static int ListenPort { get; set; }
    public static int NumberOfOutgoingLines { get; set; }

    public static void Load(FrameSettings settings)
    {
        ListenPort = settings.ListenPort;
        NumberOfOutgoingLines = settings.NumberOfOutgoingLines;
    }
}
public class FrameSettings
{
    [YAXErrorIfMissed(YAXExceptionTypes.Warning, DefaultValue = 5060)]
    public int ListenPort { get; set; }
    [YAXErrorIfMissed(YAXExceptionTypes.Warning, DefaultValue = 5)]
    public int NumberOfOutgoingLines { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        ListenPort = FrameworkSettings.ListenPort;
        NumberOfOutgoingLines = FrameworkSettings.NumberOfOutgoingLines;
    }
}
public class SettingsManager
{
    YAXSerializer _mSerializer;
    FrameSettings _mFrameSettings;
    public SettingsManager()
    {
        _mFrameSettings = new FrameSettings();
        if (!Directory.Exists("data"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("data");
        }
    }
    public void LoadSettings()
    {
        _mSerializer = new YAXSerializer(typeof(FrameSettings), 
                                        YAXExceptionHandlingPolicies.ThrowErrorsOnly, 
                                        YAXExceptionTypes.Warning);

        _mFrameSettings = (FrameSettings)_mSerializer.DeserializeFromFile("data\\settings.xml");
        FrameworkSettings.Load(_mFrameSettings);
    }
    public void SaveSettings()
    {
        _mFrameSettings.Save();
        _mSerializer.SerializeToFile(_mFrameSettings, "data\\settings.xml");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

static class is one way. But config files were made to hold the settings and are more appropriate and easy to use. they are accessed using ConfigurationManager class.